# Optional additional property file in spring context

Tags: java, spring

I have a default properties file that my app uses but I also need to be able to allow for an additional property file which can be specified by a -D flag on startup and will be pointing to a path on the file system (not in my classpath). What's the correct syntax to do that?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations" 
        value="classpath:/config/config.properties,file:/${additional.configs}" />
    </bean>
```

as it complained that:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config/config.properties,file://var/tmp/cfg/qa.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

It looks like the comma delimination isn't working despite me finding some examples suggesting to do it that way. I don't think I can use the list of location beans version of it since the additional attribute file is optional. Any thoughts? I am using spring 3.1.1.

Thanks!

**Update**: Using the list approach works, however how to make it optional is still outstanding.  For now I am using ignoreResourceNotFound=true, however that's not ideal because if someone mistypes the property then it won't fail...

Answer (score 1):

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/config/config.properties</value>
            <value>file:/${additional.configs}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If it still does not work, you can try to specify properties location **without slash**:

```
<value>file:${additional.configs}</value>
```

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was trying right now... it looks like the file:/ part is getting treated as a URL and it's throwing a java.net.UnknownHostException

Comment: OK so <value>file:${additional.configs}</value> works but the values in the additional config are not override the values in the first one ...

Comment: That is odd; from the javadoc for `PropertiesLoaderSupport.setLocations()`:  Note: Properties defined in later files will override properties defined earlier files, in case of overlapping keys. Hence, make sure that the most specific files are the last ones in the given list of locations.

Comment: Actually it worked with file:${...}, my logging was wrong. However, it seems to be required - if i dont specifyit i get java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${additional.configs} (No such file or directory). I can specify ignoreResourceNotFound but then I won't know when I pass in a path but it's wrong ... that second value needs to be conditionally present

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this by using a wildcard on the property file you want to be optional. e.g.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/config/config.properties</value>
            <value>file:/${additional.configs}*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Obviously you need to set the additional.configs parameter to something sensible. You can't leave it blank on systems that don't have the file, since the wildcard will then match all files! Instead you can set it to a dummy value for a non-existent file. e.g.

```
additional.config=/non-existent-file.txt
```

Spring doesn't throw an error if a wildcard doesn't match anything, so this has the affect of making this property file optional, without having to resort to ignoreResourceNotFound=true.